# c++ ifstream read can't store into short array buffer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, ifstream

i want to store the data from ifstream to short array,

but it crash it before print out run 2

```
short *Data;
// 88200 / (16/8) = 44100

size_t sdata_size = wavHeader.data_size /(wavHeader.bits_per_sample/8);

Data = new short [sdata_size];

std::cout << "run1" << std::endl;

in.read ((char*)&Data,sdata_size);

std::cout << "run2" << std::endl;
```

ok i done some correction as Alan Birtles point out,

```
short *Data;
// 88200 / (16/8) = 44100
Data = new short [wavHeader.data_size/(wavHeader.bits_per_sample/8)];

std::cout << "run1" << std::endl;

in.read ((char*)Data,wavHeader.data_size /(wavHeader.bits_per_sample/8));

std::cout << "run2" << std::endl;

in.close();

// this start point at first element and then increment to next array
short *ptr1 = Data;
// this start at the end element and then decrement to the next,
//- minus 1 for last element
 short *ptr2 = Data 
+(wavHeader.data_size/(wavHeader.bits_per_sample/8)) - 1;

for (; ptr1 < ptr2; ++ptr1, --ptr2)
{
  short tmp = *ptr1;
  *ptr1 = *ptr2;
  *ptr2 = tmp;
}
out.write ((char*)Data,wavHeader.data_size /(wavHeader.bits_per_sample/8));

// clean up the new
delete [] Data;
```

what i want to achieve is that i want to reverse the wav audio data and write it to another wav file. however the output is wrong any ideas why?

expected result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8iOb.png)

my result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgzV8.png)

Comment: ok is should be in.read ((char*)Data,wavHeader.data_size );

and fix the problem thank alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(char*)&Data` should just be `(char*)Data` and you should be creating an array of size `sdata_size / sizeof( short )` (assuming `sdata_size` is a multiple of 2).

Comment: This is C++, why are we using C style casts for?

Comment: I was just fixing the bug in his code, plus in this case you'd need a re-interpret cast anyway which is equivalent just more verbose

Comment: We should also be pointing out problematic coding styles as well, [there are benefits to using reinterpret_cast such as not accidently casting away const](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1059874016175972352)